# Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed - Angular8

Tags: angular, angular8

This Angular Code doesn't let me display the Array content from a JSON file onto a HTML. The error in console displays "Error trying to diff '[object Object]'"

This code is running on my local running Angular 8. I have tried many different methods of fetching the data and different ways of displaying in the HTML but none seem to work

```
JSON File 
{...} represent a string
{
  "APPLICATIONS": [
    {
      "APP_ID": 1,
      "APP_NAME": "...",
      "APP_SHORT_NAME": "...",
    },...


TS

export class Application {
    APP_ID: number;
    APP_NAME: string;
    APP_SHORT_NAME: string;
}


Service.TS

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Application } from '../intdets';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IntdetsService {

  private _url = "/assets/IntDet.json";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getIntdets(): Observable<Application[]> {
    return this.http.get<Application[]>(this._url);
  }
}


Component.TS 

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IntdetsService } from '../service/intdets.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-intdets',
  templateUrl: './intdets.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./intdets.component.css']
})
export class IntdetsComponent implements OnInit {

  public apps = [];

  constructor(private _intdetsService: IntdetsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._intdetsService.getIntdets()
        .subscribe(data => this.apps = data);
  }

}

HTML

<ul *ngFor = "let app of apps">
  <li>{{app.APP_ID}}</li> //Test code to only print one element
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you try to just console.log(apps) without the ngFor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what Im seeing, the data coming back from the service is not an array, its an object containing a property that is an array. So `this.apps = { APPLICATIONS: [] }` and if you want to iterate the array you need to access APPPLICATIONS like this:

```
<ul *ngFor = "let app of apps.APPLICATIONS">
  <li>{{app.APP_ID}}</li> //Test code to only print one element
</ul>
```